# Media queries not working on windows server

Tags: html, .net, css, twitter-bootstrap, media-queries

I have been developing a static HTML site using bootstrap 3 and media queries. It worked fine when working through a simple LAMP stack. However, I handed the exact same files over to our back end .NET guys and the media queries do not work. All code is identical. I'm using a mobile first approach and only the last media query is being executed. Below is how my media queries are structured. I have tried every available syntax for media queries and still no luck...

```
@media (min-width: 768px) {}

@media (min-width: 992px) {}

@media (min-width: 1200px) {}
```

Comment: What browser are you using it in?

Comment: I have tested in all browsers. With a cleared cache.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue was due to a hidden character in my last media query. My text editor did not pick it up and was just a case of re-writing the media query and containing styles. Windows server was just more sensitive to this than Apache.

Answer (score 0):

Add this meta tag in your html file

```
<head>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
</head>
```

Hope this one help you